# AHK - Google Chrome specific hot strings

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to create Google Chrome specific hot strings. The problem is, that for some strange reason SetTitleMatchMode doesn't seem to working. Here is my example code:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive, Chrome
:*:mail::testmailaddress@innowhere.com
```

I also tried with REGEX setting but it doesn't work as well

```
SetTitleMatchMode, REGEX
```

To make things working i have to change 2nd line to #IfWinActive  otherwise it doesn't work, but I would like to make it more general. Any ideas?

Comment: Better use something like [RoboForm](http://alternativeto.net/software/roboform/)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome doesn't have "Chrome" in its title. You can check for the process instead.

```
#if WinActive("ahk_exe chrome.exe")
    :*:mail::testmailaddress@innowhere.com
#if
```

Comment: you have few errors in your script. first of all it is called #IfWinActive and secondly there is a comma after it. And beside this. It seems to not working as well

Comment: @Kajiyama [#If](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_If.htm), [WinActive()](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/WinActive.htm). I don't see any errors in my script. It's a different way of using the #if directive which is much more flexible. Make sure you're using the latest version of AHK [(v1.1.16.04)](http://ahkscript.org/docs/AHKL_ChangeLog.htm#v1.1.16.04) and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
:*:mail::testmailaddress@innowhere.com
```

Use AU3_Spy(C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AU3_Spy.exe) for get the information about the window.